# Merge two arrays and insert blank spots where there isn't a match

Tags: php, arrays

i'm building a request for dates and i need to build an array but keep it in the format of a five day week, so i can easily output it into a table.

i have this array of the current weekdays, monday to friday, that looks like this

```
$weekDays( [0] => 2016-12-19 [1] => 2016-12-20 [2] => 2016-12-21 [3] => 2016-12-22 [4] => 2016-12-23 )
```

and an array from a user, which has his personalized dates in it

```
$user( [0] => 2016-12-20 [1] => 2016-12-21 [2] => 2016-12-22)
```

as you can see, it's only three of the five dates this week. i need to merge these two arrays where the dates match but keep the five day format, like so

```
$userThisWeek([0] => NULL [1] => 2016-12-20 [2] => 2016-12-21 [3] => 2016-12-22 [4] => NULL)
```

how can i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
// $weekDays( [0] => 2016-12-19 [1] => 2016-12-20 [2] => 2016-12-21 [3] => 2016-12-22 [4] => 2016-12-23 );
   // $user( [0] => 2016-12-20 [1] => 2016-12-21 [2] => 2016-12-22);
    $userThisWeek = array();
    foreach($weekDays as $key=>$value){
       if (array_search($value, $user) === FALSE)
          $userThisWeek[$key] = NULL;
       else
          $userThisWeek[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$userThisWeek = [];

foreach ($weekDays as $key => $day) {
    if (in_array($day, $user) {
        $userThisWeek[$key] = $day;
    } else {
        $userThisWeek[$key] = null;
    }
}
```